# Reducing dimension with PCA ($\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, pca, computational-statistics

I have been given a few points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I want to apply PCA to reduce its dimensions to 1. 
Here is the question: 
[image]

I'm trying to apply a linear regression model by hand.
I will be happy to receive some help here.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This seems to assume that you then fit some kind of model. Do you fit a linear regression on that one variable? Also, is this for a class? If so, please add the self-study tag and read its Wiki. What, if any, software tools are you allowed to use for this assignment?

Comment: Hi!
I am not allowed  to use any program. I'm trying to apply a linear model regression.
I need to apply it only by hand.

Comment: Well you know how to do the PCA by hand via eigenvalues and eigenvectors, right? Start with that.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. How do I conduct the matrix to find the eigenvalues?

Comment: Well what do you know about PCA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first estimate the covariance (or correlation) matrix and find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. The slope of the first eigenvector is what you want.

This in general is **not** the same as the slope of the regression of either $y$ on $x$ or $x$ on $y$, but rather the slope of the orthogonal regression.